# Recycleview notifyDataSetChanged() erro

Tags: java, android, android-logcat

I have tried to look at other answers but they don't address my case. I get the error with my recyclerview each time I want to load item in a recyview with endless scrolling. At times it loads items to the recyclerview and at other times it leaves the recycle view blank given a message on the logcat as below.

```
IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling
```

My class of application is as

```
itemAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new Schoolarship_Adapter.OnLoadMoreListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {
            listItem.add(null);
            itemAdapter.notifyItemInserted(listItem.size() - 1);

            final Handler handler = new Handler();

            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    listItem.remove(listItem.size() - 1);
                    itemAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(listItem.size());

                    ++pagenumber;
                    new RetrieveItems().execute();
                    System.out.println("working now i guess");

                    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    itemAdapter.setLoaded();

                }
            };

            handler.post(r);
        }
    });
```

My Adapter looks like

```
Schoolarship_Adapter(Context cont, List<Schoolarship> items, @NonNull RecyclerView rv){
    context = cont;
    listItems = items;

    if((rv.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager)) {
        final LinearLayoutManager gm = (LinearLayoutManager) rv.getLayoutManager();
        rv.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy){
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                totalItemCount = gm.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = gm.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if(!loading &&totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)){
                    if(onLoadMoreListener!=null){
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Pls, why do I still get that error each time I run this app?

Comment: `new RetrieveItems().execute()` loads your data?

Comment: yes it does loads my data

Comment: Why do you have a `notifyDataSetChanged` after that statement? The idea is notify the adapter **after** the data has been loaded completely. When you call notify there the data will not be completely loaded. You should be writing the `notifyDataSetChanged` inside `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask` `RetrieveItems`.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this is ,in your onLoadMore() 
it will compute the height of your recyclerView  when new items is added/loaded so when you give notifyDataSetChanged it will definitely throw exception.
May be this will work

```
protected void postAndNotifyAdapter(final Handler handler, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!recyclerView.isComputingLayout()) {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    postAndNotifyAdapter(handler, recyclerView, adapter);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I don't think i understand you perfectly, that happens to be the code ruuning already in my activity

Comment: Did you try this out ?